# How to emit signal from static function in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, static, signals, gstreamer

I am trying to emit signal from a static member function to another slot from same member in QT 5.

In my code, I have to call a static Gstreamer function which I made as a member of MainWindow so that it could emit signal to other MainWindow slots. My code is like this:

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


ui->setupUi(this);


connect(this, SIGNAL(emitSignal(int)), this, 
SLOT(signal_triggered(int)));

  GMainLoop *loop = NULL;
  gst_init (0, NULL);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
 ...........
...........

decoder_src_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (decoder, "src");
  if (!decoder_src_pad)
    g_print ("Unable to get src pad\n");
  else
    gst_pad_add_probe (decoder_src_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
        decoder_src_pad_buffer_probe, NULL, NULL);   // Must require 
Static function for CALLBACK

g_main_loop_run (loop);

}


GstPadProbeReturn decoder_src_pad_buffer_probe (GstPad * pad, 
GstPadProbeInfo * info, gpointer u_data)
{
GstBuffer *buf = (GstBuffer *) info->data;

int foo = 8;

emit emitSignal(foo); 

return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

void MainWindow::signal_triggered(int indx)
{

emit requestUpdate(indx); // Signal is connected to another class

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
static GstPadProbeReturn decoder_src_pad_buffer_probe (GstPad * pad, 
GstPadProbeInfo * info, gpointer u_data);

public slots:
void signal_triggered(int);
signals:
void emitSignal(int index);
private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
.......
.......
}
```

But the QT compiler gives error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:116: error: cannot call member function ‘void MainWindow::emitSignal(int)’ without object
```

I also have tried

```
emit ui->emitSignal(foo);
```

But it also gives error:

```
error: invalid use of member ‘MainWindow::ui’ in static member function emit ui->emitSignal(foo);
```

Comment: Try to replace static method with singleton instance of `QObject` what will include all signals you need

Comment: To emit a signal, you need a signal instance. The signal is member of a class derived from `QObject`. Hence, you need an instance of that container object. If you want to emit the signal from a callback function you have to pass the address of the instance as client data. Then emit the signal for that instance.

Comment: As the compiler says, you just can not do that. Signals are emitted from object instances, a static function is never called for an instance. If you tell us more about your problem, we might suggest a solution....

Comment: @SerhiyKulish Please don't suggest or do that. This is the kind of singleton abuse that will get you into deep trouble later on, and make the software unmaintainable...

Comment: Btw. Qt widget applications need a runtime loop to come alive. That's what happens when you call `QApplication::exec()`. If you start another (Glib) runtime loop in e.g. the constructor of `MainWindow`, you will never reach your necessary call of `QApplication::exec()` (or at least, much too late).

Comment: Thats true, @Scheff . But its possible to remove `g_main_loop_run (loop)` and execute `g_main_iteration(false)` within **while()** or **for loop** gives better control over g_main_loop

Comment: I strongly assume, that call of `g_main_iteration(false)` has to happen out of the event loop of Qt. This might be done e.g. using a `QTimer`. The `interval` of that `QTimer` might be set sufficiently small although I'm afraid that `0` may cause unintended high load on one CPU core. Btw. [`g_main_iteration()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-iteration) is marked as deprecated. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Static functions cannot access non-static members or functions (you do not have a `this` pointer).

As such you can't (directly) emit a signal from a static function - which QObject is supposed to be the emitter of that signal (i.e. which QObject would you `connect` to?)

Ask yourself instead: "Why am I trying to emit a signal from a static function?" and try to discover and resolve the underlying issue. You will save yourself a lot of headache in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton pattern. Make your class like this:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/amin-amani/DesignPatternsCPP/tree/master/DesignPatterns/8-SingleTone)

and use emit like this:

```
    emit yourclassInstance->DataReady(samples);
```

Answer (score 0):

> mainwindow.cpp:116: error: cannot call member function ‘void MainWindow::emitSignal(int)’ without object

The error is explicit.

In fact, a signal (like every non-static members/methods of a class) relies on a living instance of the class. A `static` method does not require to create any instance so using the signals of the related class is impossible (the same way if you tried to access a non-static member/method of the related class).

If you want to send this signal, either you have to remove the `static` specifier (which is not what you seem to want) or you can pass a reference of an instance of the class as parameter of the `static` function (and send the desired signal from **and for** that instance).

Comment: I have also thought about that way (i.e.  pass a reference of an instance of the class as parameter of the static function) but since its still unclear to me how to pass argument to GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, I haven't tried that.

Comment: @AbuAnasShuvom I mean passing it as a parameter of `decoder_src_pad_buffer_probe()` (which is the `static` function). I don't know what `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` is but the code is not complete enough for me to be able to understand the real problem. Anyway I hope it can help you to find a proper solution :)